# Simplifying series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

I have the following sum:

$\sum _{k=1}^{n-1}\:\left(1+2\left(n-k\right)+2\right)\left(n-k\right)+1+\sum _{k=1}^{n-1}\:\left(1+\left(n-k\right)+\left(n-k-1\right)+1\right)$

I need to write the final answer in terms of $n$.

I understand that the final answer is approximately $\frac{2}{3}n^3$, but I am not entirely sure how it is reached.

I assume I could use one of the following formulas:

$\sum _{k=1}^n\:k=\frac{1}{2}n\left(n+1\right)$

or

$\sum _{k=1}^n\:k^2=\frac{1}{6}n\left(n+1\right)\left(2n+1\right)$

But I am not entirely sure how I would apply them here.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Notice that $n$ and $k$ only appear in the form $n-k$ in all the expressions. There, we see that perhaps it would be smart to "reverse" the summation, so that instead of
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}
$$
you could have a variable $d=n-k$ and use that instead of $k$ in the summation

Comment: Second comment: You have a lot of unsimplified terms in the expression. For example:
$$
(1+2(n-k)+2) (n-k) = 3(n-k) + 2(n-k)^2
$$
That looks better, right? Now you can substitute a value for $n-k$ ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is $\frac{1}{6}(n - 1)(4n^2 + 13n + 12)$ which is approximately $\frac{2}{3}n^3$ as noted. The summation term simplifies to $2k^2 - k(4n+ 5) + (2n^2 + 5n + 2)$ in descending powers of $k$. The two identities above can then be applied along with $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} 1 = n-1$, to give the answer.

In more detail, $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} 2k^2 - k(4n+ 5) + (2n^2 + 5n + 2)   = 2\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k^2 - (4n + 5) \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} k + (2n^2 + 5n + 2) \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} 1. $

This is equal to $\frac{2}{6} (n-1) n (2n -1) - (4n + 5)\frac{1}{2}(n-1)n + (2n^2 + 5n + 2)(n-1)$. The term $n-1$ is a common factor, and simplifying the expression gives the answer above: $\frac{1}{6}(n - 1)(4n^2 + 13n + 12)$.

Comment: I provided help and someone downvoted my answer. What is the issue, please? I have added more detail. Is something unclear?